# Why is there a long delay between WCF TransportReceive and ServiceLevelReceiveReply?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have two environments running the same WCF web service but one of them seems to have a 3-5 minute delay returning the XML data.  The slow down seems to occur in relation to the size of the data being returned.  The web service just retrieves an XML string from a database so the processing time is constant.

The endpoint bindings are the same for both but I'm wondering what else would cause a delay.

I ran a trace and it shows that the TransportReceive happens at the same time on both environments, but on the delayed environment the ServiceLevelReceiveReply occurs after 3-5 minutes.

Any idea what could cause this?  I'm happy to provide as much data as possible.

[image: trace log]

[image]

Here are the two bindings that are used.  MyPolicySoap is used for getting the XML.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyPolicySoap" closeTimeout="00:11:00" openTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="5000000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
         <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
         <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""><!--<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />--></transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</wshttpbinding>
```

Comment: What channel stack are you using?

Comment: @LuizFelipe I'm not sure what you mean, but in the bindings we have security set to None and it is using buffered messages.  I just posted the bindings in case that helps.

Comment: Yes, the channel stack are the binding configurations. I thought there was Reliable session binding inside a custom binding, sometimes it introduce delays, but you only have a Http Transport binding and an Text encoding (they are what make the basic http binding). Is there another behavior being added at runtime? Where are you hosting the service?

Comment: No other behaviors.  I really don't know enough information about it I guess.  The issue is being reported from a customer across the country and I can't recreate the delay on my end.  I was hoping there might be some common areas to look at that would cause it.

Comment: I see that the proxy (I presume that it is a proxy client because it received a reply from a sent request) is running inside an IIS server. Perhaps there is problems in the throttling configuration of IIS, something with the Threadpool. http://mohandeval.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/optimizing-iis7-5-performance/

Comment: See if this is related: [WCF service may scale up slowly under load](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826).